# On windows services set startup type to Automatic (Delayed start) is bad or not?

Tags: windows-10, anti-virus, windows-services, eset

I have installed an antivirus on my computer and it has a service,by default it's startup type is Automatic but because of some bug or ... when i boot my windows this service stops working and i should start it manually,BUT if i set it to Delayed start, everything work fine.

I read some post and i know the different between starting Automatic vs Automatic (Delayed start) BUT the question is:

This is an antivirus and because of this changing startup type (for my computer is) dangerous or not ?

Comment: It's still going to be started all you are doing is delaying when that happens for a period of time.  If you find the risk (basic non-existing) unacceptable then use a different security package that doesn't have compatible issues with Windows 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand your concern, but consider this; Antivirus will not scan or attempt to stop the loading of low level OS components like drivers once they are installed (eg Root/Boot Kits). That means that having it come online earlier won't do you any good. The only concern is whether it is loaded before userspace apps begin to execute, so it can intercept malcode BEFORE it is installed.